# How to find all the equivalent matrices of a matrix in R?

Tags: r, matrix, permutation, equivalent

I want to find all the equivalent matrices of a matrix, let's say it as M,
but I want these equivalent matrices to have exactly the same diagonal elements with M and the same non-diagonal elements with M.

For example if M is

```
> M<-matrix(x,4,4);M
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]   22   -2   -2    2
[2,]   -2   22    2    2
[3,]   -2    2   22   -2
[4,]    2    2   -2   22
```

I want one of the equivalent matrix to be for example

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]   22    2   -2    2
[2,]    2   22    2   -2
[3,]   -2    2   22   -2
[4,]    2   -2   -2   22
```

As you can see not only M,but also all the equivalent matrices must be symmetric (M=transpose(M)).

I have tried lots of ways, such as "permut" and "Matrix" packages, but I can't find something to help me.
I have used LU and QR decomposition, but it's not what I want.

Is there something to do with this problem???

Thank you all!

Comment: It seems you want `diag(s)*M*diag(s)` where `s[k] in {-1,+1}`.

Comment: To clarify: you don't care (other than symmetry) how the lower diagonal elements are arranged, just that the two matrices have the same collection?   If that's the case,  you might find (shameless plug) `vecsets` package helpful in verifying that the contents of the lower triangles are the same.

Comment: LutzL, I want something like that.
So, I want M=P*M1*P', where M1 is equivalent to M and P is a permutation matrix.

Comment: Carl Witthoft, I am gonna see the `vecsets`! Thanks for it!

Comment: Carl Witthoft, `vecsets` doesn't work! Thanks for it!

Comment: The answer is `rmperm {sna}`.

Comment: Vassilis: good that you found something which works.  For reference, the way to write a function and its package is  `sna:rmperm` , the way you'd call it from the command line.